# Print histogram for each of the columns in my table with one single command

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I would like to draw a histogram for each of the columns in my data.frame without having to write the the names of all of them, similar to what I did for inspect their unique values with:

```
sapply(data, unique)
```

So I tried

```
sapply(data, hist)
```

This command draws the histogram correctly, but the title for each of them is "Histogram of X[[i]]":

[image]

How can I draw the histograms but with the correct title?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data with ```dput()```?
It will be easier for everyone to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it with the following code:

```
for (col in 2:ncol(data)) {
    hist(data[,col], main=colnames(data)[col],  xlab=colnames(data)[col])
}
```